# Does restoring my iPhone 6 remove my iTunes balance or phone number?

Tags: ios, itunes, restore, iphone

I want to restore my iPhone 6 because I can't temper my restrictions passcode. Will restoring my iPhone also take away the money I have in my iTunes gift card? And will my phone number be deleted too?

Comment: Restoring it to a backup containing the restrictions passcode will achieve nothing, the passcode is stored in the backup too. You'd need to set it up as a new device. Gift cards are linked to your iCloud account not the device & your phone number is assigned by your service provider & enabled by the appropriate SIM card.

Answer (score 3):

The money in your iTunes account will remain as it is linked to your iTunes account (the Apple ID) rather than the specific device. Your phone number is obtained through the SIM card in the device, so this is not affected by restoring either.